# Headers in http source Spring cloud flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using postman to POST a http request with a file in form-data and want to pass the filename as a header. With file as a sink i want to get that file and save it in the name of the header value filename which i passed in the http request. Below is what i tried with spring cloud flow and i am not getting the header "filename" in the sink side the file is getting saved in the name "null"

```
stream create --name myfilestream --definition "http --mapped-request-headers=foo --port=5555 | file --directory-expression="'Desktop' + 'sr'" --name-expression="headers['foo']" --deploy
```

Could someone throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kafka Binder , you should consider to use this option:

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers
>   The list of custom headers that will be transported by the binder.
>
> Default: empty.

By default custom headers aren't transported.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. My binder is kafka, and i tried setting app.http.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=foo and passed the same in the header during the POST method but that has not passed.                     2017-06-24 19:43:37,014 DEBUG -kafka-listener-1 o.s.i.f.FileWritingMessageHandler:115 - fileWritingMessageHandler received message: GenericMessage [payload=hellojjoj;o, headers={kafka_offset=0, id=fd06a55e-1ade-7f76-985c-4da54f971245, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, kafka_receivedTopic=gf.http, timestamp=1498313616997}]

Comment: Can you confirm that this `foo` header is really sent to the Binder from the HTTP app? Would you mind to switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` - `app.http.logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG` and observe the `output` message with its headers? Also be sure that you use `headerMode` as `embeddedHeaders` for really headers carrying.

Comment: That partly helped now i am able to see the foo value in the http source log(added embedded headers property in both producer and consumer), but the same is not passing over to sink, i am trying to create a dynamic filename with that foo value. I am using the same DSL to create the stream which i have in the question above. The data is getting populated to a file named "null".  `2017-06-27 11:18:47,188 DEBUG .. message: GenericMessage [payload=knknkn, headers={http_requestMethod=POST, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8001/, foo=1234,.., timestamp=1498542527188}]`